# JavaScript Regular Expression : I want to replace last 4 words of my variables

Tags: javascript, regex, spring, web, replace

I'm currently making an e-commerce website with Spring, Java and Javascript.
I want to hide the last four words of the users when they register a question like

hello123 >> hell****
stackoverflow >> stackover****

This is the code that I've written in my jsp.

```
<table>
<td id="userId">${ qna.userId }</td>
</table>

<script>
var userId = document.getElementById("userId");
    
    function maskingNumbers(userId) {
           return userId.replace(/\d(?=\d{4})/g, "*");
         }
</script>
```

Well, my "userId" still prints out on its original form.
It would be really thankful if you be specific with the steps.

Comment: `string. substring(0, string.length() - 4) + "****"`

Comment: Your text says you want to "hide" the last for *words*, while your examples seem to hide the last four *characters*. Which is it?

Comment: Oh, and your sample code seems to aim at *digits*, which is another thing entirely...

Answer (score 1):

You're asking for "words" replacement as your example seems to show "character" replacement, which is way easier. And your regular expression seems to target digits as @JohannesH pointed out.

Try this expression

```js
userId.replace(/\w{4}$/g, "****")
```

The regular expression `\w{4}$` targets the last four word-characters (meaning digits or letters or `_`) in the input

***Edit after a little more thinking***

The answer I gave you will fail if there is any space or symbol within those last 4 chars. You'd rather just use the `.`, that represents any character

```js
userId.replace(/.{4}$/g, "****")
```

And you'll have to handle cases where your input has less than 4 characters to begin with...

try here:
https://regex101.com/r/HyXUp1/2

***More edit after more thinking***

Your question seemed really simple on the surface, but called for a lot more when trying to answer thoroughly. Thanks to the other users for their comments. I hesitated giving a second answer for the following:

As I pointed out, you should also think about cases where there are 4 characters or less in the input. You could end up with very complicated code for that... Or use the solution below (explaining after)

```js
function maskInput(input) {
    return input.replace(/(.?)(.{1,4})$/g, '$1****').substr(0, input.length);
}
```

The regular expression `(.?)(.{1,4})$` will match up to 4 characters at the end, preceded by 1 other character (optionally). And this preceding character will be captured in group number 1 (first set of parenthesis). Test it here https://regex101.com/r/HyXUp1/3

The replacement will spit out the first captured group (`$1`) and then 4 stars in place of all the matched characters (leaving the beginning intact). This will however give a result too long by a few stars if the string is shorter than 5 characters.

So we cut out the result before it became too long using the original string's length with method `String.substr`

```js
const inputs = [
    'Find the last 4 chars in this sentence',
    'Stackoverflow',
    'I\'m a smart monk3y',
    'I\'m a dumb m0nk@y',
    '6chars',
    '5chrs',
    '4crs',
    '3cr',
    '2c',
    '1',
];

function maskInput(input) {
    return input.replace(/(.?)(.{1,4})$/g, '$1****').substr(0, input.length);
}

inputs.forEach(input => console.log(input, '->', maskInput(input)));
```

Comment: DId you test your code?  It wil turn "foobar" into "fo*" - just one star, not four, as the entire match will be replaced by the entire replacement.

Comment: For `\w` you should also mention `_` being part of it. And with the last suggested approach of yours one also can immediately switch back to *Berto99*'s approach or something similar like ... `str.slice(0, -4) + '****'`.

Comment: @PeterSeliger correct, but that's what the OP seemed to be asking for, and Berto99 hasn't given an answer but merely a comment, so what's your point ?

Comment: The point is, that in case you finally figured out the OP's needs, you provide the simplest approach. Thus, no need for any regex based solution. Just change your answer accordingly. (And please calm down, there was nothing offending in my comment).

Comment: @PeterSeliger OK sorry the tone seemed a little angrier than I actually was. It just didn't seem to make any difference and the OP was asking a question about regex, so it seemed more natural and informative to answer using regex.

Comment: @julien.giband ... thanks for the changes, you've got my upvote.